# What is meant by "striking one another's necks" in the hadith

Tags: practical-islam, source-identification, islamic-basis, hadith-interpretation

What is meant by "striking one another's necks" in the  following hadith:

> It was narrated that Salamah bin Nufail al-Kindi said: "I was sitting with the Messenger of Allah (SAW) when a man said: 'O Messenger of Allah! The people have lost interest in horses and put down their weapons, and they say there is no Jihad, and that war has ended.' The Messenger of Allah (SAW) turned to face him and said: 'They are lying, now the fighting is to come. There will always be a group among my Ummah who will fight for the truth, for whom Allah will cause some people to deviate, and grant them provision from them, until the Hour begins and until the promise of Allah comes. Goodness is tied to the forelocks of horses until the Day of Resurrection. **It has been revealed to me that I am going to die and will not stay long, and you will follow me group after striking one another's necks. And the place of safety for the believers is Ash-Sham**.'" [Sunan al-Nasa'i (6/214) No. 3561]صحيح، رواه الامام احمد والنسائى وحسنه الالباني في الصحيحة 4/603

Answer (score 2):

To strike one another's neck means to go against each other. This could mean arguments, fights and wars.

Answer (score 0):

> **striking one another's necks**

Means that Muslims will be divided in groups killing each other.

> **And the place of safety for the believers is Ash-Sham**

Like the Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) has pointed to the Ash-Sham at the time of tribulation to be safe that day, and the people of Islam are safer there.